# Find a dot in a string?

Tags: java, regex

How can I find if a string starts with a `.` or has a `.` with a preceding `/`.

So `.` or `/.`

I've tried:

```
^[^\.].*$
```

But this fails to catch anything starting with a `/`

Comment: What have you tried? What is the *precise* code that you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have? Do you get an error message? If yes, which one? Does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior? If yes, what is the observed behavior, and in which way does it differ from the expected behavior?

Comment: I have what ive tried in my question

Comment: please paste your java code so we can test it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^/?\\..*$
```

This matches an optional slash and a dot at the begining of a string.

According to comment, I guess you want to match:

```
/?\\.[^/.]+$
```

This matches an optional slash fllowed by a dot then 1 or more characters that are not slash or dot, at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks ive seen your edit, still doesnt work for /some-path/.some-file

Comment: @panthro: Do you want to match the begining of the string or not? If not, please edit your question and add some test cases

Comment: I want to match where it's .file or /path/.file or /.file or even /path/path/.file

Comment: @panthro: What doesn'twork? Please, give some test cases with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`^\.` or `^[.]` will match a leading dot. also `^[/][.]` will match starting `/.`

Comment: in what language are you trying to use it? it works in bash

Comment: @panthro *"java please"* so why didn't you post that in your question? Here I am asking why it was added in an edit by Toto.

Answer (score 0):

`^[\/\.].*$` will check if the string starts with a **.** or an **/**.

Here is java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegexTester
{
    final static String regex = "^[\\/\\.].*$";
    final static String[] stringsToTest = { ".file",
                                            "./file",
                                            "/file",
                                            "/.file",
                                            ".",
                                            "./",
                                            "/some/path",
                                            "/some-path/.some-file",
                                            "/path/path/.file",
                                            "/path/.file",
                                            "/asfas/.d",
                                            "/path/.file" };

    final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for (String text : stringsToTest) {
            testRegex(text);
        }       
    }

    public static void testRegex(String testString) 
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);

        while (matcher.find()) 
        {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));

            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) 
            {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
javac RegexTester.java && java RegexTester
```

> Full match: .file
>   Full match: ./file
>   Full match: /file
>   Full match: /.file
>   Full match: .
>   Full match: ./
>   Full match: /some/path
>   Full match: /some-path/.some-file
>   Full match: /path/path/.file
>   Full match: /path/.file
>   Full match: /asfas/.d
>   Full match: /path/.file

**[Run this java code in rextester.com](http://rextester.com/SSUHN88391)**

Comment: @panthro : It works on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4myqSI/1) and on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3g1ir).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this  `^[\/|\.].?` but It would be better to post a sample of what you are trying to find and where.

Edit

this should do it `^[\/|\.]+`

Comment: Paste an sample of text you are looking in.
It does work here : https://regex101.com/

Comment: .file or /.file or /path/.file

Comment: I dont really understand now what it is you want to achieve do you want match each `./` `.` or `/.` in a line or in each row from start as in after new line?

Answer (score 0):

For the question as you've posted it: No regex required.

```
String s =  ...;
s.startsWith(".") || s.startsWith("/.")
```

If you want regex, because it's cool, use this

```
String s = ...;
boolean matches = s.matches("/?\\..*");
```

(Based on your comments) If you want to check something like the last segment in a path

```
String s = ...;
boolean matches = s.matches("(.*/)?\\..*"); // matches also path/to/.file
```

If your actually matching file names, you should prefer [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

```
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/.file");
boolean isHidden = path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(".");
```

Comment: @panthro the PHP related question was closed?